# C, OpenMP: How can I make this parallisation of a triple loop better?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, nested-loops

I'm trying to parallelise the [Floyd-Warshall](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Floyd-Warshall%27s_Algorithm) algorithm using OpenMP (basically editing a 2D array in-place), but I doubt that I'm going about it in the best way, here is what I've got so far:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k) shared(g)
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
            for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ ) {
                g->A[j][k] = imin( g->A[j][k], g->A[j][i] + g->A[i][k] );
            }
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas how I can utilise OpenMP better? At the moment that just halves runtime, surely that can be improved.

Also if anyone as any suggestions for other technologies to be used for the parallelisation, I'm all ears. I thought about MPI, but I'd have to make my whole `main` function parallel right?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The code above does not work, the answers below show why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallelizing the algorithm is not straightforward.  See the notes here
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node35.html
for information on running it in parallel.  If you have a small number of processors (dual-, quad-, oct- core machine) then Parallel Floyd 1 is probably right for you.  If you have a huge number of processors (really awesome GPU, mesh computer) then Parallel Floyd 2 might be better.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Charles, could you help me parse it into my head a little better? As I understand it, you split the rows up into R/N chunks, where R is number or rows and N is number of threads/processors, then you broadcast the 'edge' rows to the other processes. Am I understanding this correctly and is this even possible with OpenMP? thanks.

Comment: It should be possible, yes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6030658/341362 for OpenMP code (solving a different problem) that seems to use the techniques you'll need.